# Using google places service with php curl

Tags: google-maps, curl, google-places-api

im trying to use the google places service with php curl

in my for loop (2 laps) , i send my url,
at the 1 lap, i can get json informations but the 2nd lap give me "REQUEST_DENIED" status. Here is my code :

```
<?php

//header("content-type: application/json"); 
//header("content-type: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header("content-type: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit","12000M");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', True);

$cumulResults = array();
$pagenext="";

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
    try{
        $curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=50000&sensor=false&keyword=doctor&key=myapikeysecret'.$pagenext,
        ));

        if(!curl_exec($curl)){
            die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
        }

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        $result = json_decode($resp, true) ;

        if(array_key_exists( 'status', $result  )  )
        {
            switch ($result['status'])
            {
                case "OK":
                    break;
                case "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":
                    case "INVALID_REQUEST":
                    case "REQUEST_DENIED":
                    //echo $result['status'];
                    //exit;
                    break;
            }
        }

        print_r($result );

        if (array_key_exists('next_page_token', $result ) )
        {
            $pagenext = "&pagenex="+$result['next_page_token'];
        }else{
            $pagenext = "";
        }

        if($curl){curl_close($curl);}
        sleep(5);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if($curl){curl_close($curl);}
    }
}

?>
```

thanks

Comment: i use sleep function (5 secs ), how much time do you suggest to wait ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [sleep](https://www.php.net/sleep) to wait the thread between calls? Perhaps they are executing too quickly and hitting the request speed limit. Most Google maps services have them but they're not very well documented.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i found the problem : i replaced  $pagenext = "&pagenex="+$result['next_page_token']; by  $pagenext = "&pagetoken=".$result['next_page_token'];

Comment: Thanks dude, I write a sleep(2) and the code works.